# SHELL :Extract a string betwen two characters in different states

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I have a simple variable string which comes in two possibles forms :

**1. First case** : tag=v1.0.2-15 , or tag=v2.0.2-15 ....

**2. second case :** tag=v1.0.2 , or tag=v1.1.2 .....

I need to extract always **the numeric part** which is  just **after "v"** and **before "-" (for the first case )** and **with the last numeric char (for the second case )**

to obtain finally this form of output : **1.0.2**  or **1.0.2** ...

I have already used this command to get it with the first case :

```
grep -oP "(?<=v).+(?=-)"
```

but i still not able to patch it for the second problem , *by the way i need a command which deals with both cases in the same time* 
**any suggestions ??**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just use :

```
(?<=v)[0-9\.]+
```

[Here](https://regex101.com/r/i1J8Tw/1)'s an example.

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -oP '(?<=v)[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)*'
```

This looks for a `v` (not part of the match) followed by string consisting of one or more digits followed by one or more strings consisting of a dot followed by one or more digits.

Comment: this is the best response

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this one : `grep -oP "[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]"` ?

Answer (score 1):

No need for the external `grep` program:

`tag=${tag%%-*}` will strip all characters after the `-` if they exist.
`tag=${tag:1}` will remove the first character (the "v").

```
tag=v1.0.2-15
tag=${tag%%-*}
echo ${tag:1}

tag=v2.0.2-15
tag=${tag%%-*}
echo ${tag:1}

tag=v1.0.2
tag=${tag%%-*}
echo ${tag:1}

tag=v1.1.2
tag=${tag%%-*}
echo ${tag:1}
```

Gives:

```
1.0.2
2.0.2
1.0.2
1.1.2
```

Comment: "tag=v1.0.2-15"  is coming as an output of another script (string ; it's not a shell variable)

Comment: @firasKoubaa:  you can make it a variable using `tag=$(another-script)`

Answer (score 1):

```
awk -F'[-v]' '{print $2}'
```

would be an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Using a `regEx` in `bash`, with the `~` operator ( supported from `bash 3.0` onwards)

```
[[ $tag =~ ^v([[:digit:]|.]+).* ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

*Pipe* the output from your command to this, as

```
cmd | while read -r line; do [[ $tag =~ ^v([[:digit:]|.]+).* ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"; done
```

Some *examples* for your reference,

```
tag="v1.0.2-15"
[[ $tag =~ ^v([[:digit:]|.]+).* ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
1.0.2

tag="v1.0.2"
[[ $tag =~ ^v([[:digit:]|.]+).* ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
1.0.2

tag="v1.0.2-v1.2.9.2"
[[ $tag =~ ^v([[:digit:]|.]+).* ]] && printf "%s\n" "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
1.0.2
```